VBA Fahrenheit to Celsius
How do I write this function?
Function Fahrenheit2C()
    Dim f As Integer
    ' Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius
    Fahrenheit2C = (f - 32) / 1.8
End Function

I get "value errors", even though I am entering integers. Not sure what the issue here is. I tried to ask AI, but it is not working.

Dividing by 1.8 doesn't often return an Integer...

I would suggest NOT writing this function at all. Excel has built in functionality for converting basic units =CONVERT().  In your case it would be =CONVERT(number, "F","C").  There is no point of re-inventing the wheel.

You need to have an input value to utilize for the conversion:
Function ConvertFtoC(F As Double) As Double
    ConvertFtoC = (F - 32) * 5 / 9
End Function


Why the gymnastics with integers in the formula?  Why not ConvertFtoC = (F - 32#) * 1.8

@chrisneilsen because i'm old and have always done 5/9  for f->c and 9/5 for c->f.  I also just learned about convert() from michael's response, so can work to drop this existing formula from a list of functions.
